# Error por consola (variable no definida) aún cuando se declara antes del ciclo por conteo "for"

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, bucles, while

En este código busco eliminar un error por consola donde aparece que en la línea 8 "resultado is not defined"...

- Traté solo de declarar la variable "resultado" (incluso inicializándola en = 0) antes de comenzar el ciclo do... while y solo reasignar el valor dentro del ciclo pero entra en un ciclo infinito.
- Traté de declarar con var y reasignar el valor dentro del ciclo pero ocurrió lo mismo (ciclo infinito).

Entiendo que sería un problema de scope pues la variable "resultado" solo está "viviendo" dentro del ciclo for, pero no termino de comprender el error, pues pensé que lo solucionaría de alguna de las dos maneras anteriores.

```
let ingresarNumero = parseInt(prompt("Ingresa un numero o si quieres salir ingresa esc"));

do {
      for (let i = 1; i<= 10; i++) {
          let resultado = ingresarNumero * i ;
          alert (ingresarNumero +" X "+ i +" = "+ resultado);
      } 
} while (resultado != ("esc" && 0 && 10));
```

Comment: Cual es el problema inicial, que debe hacer tu código?

Comment: Debería multiplicar el numero que se ingresa del 1 al 10 excepto que se ingrese esc o 0, es decir, de cada número ingresado hará la tabla de multiplicar correspondiente salvo que la condición sea "esc" o el número cero

Comment: y es necesario usar do while?

Comment: No, pues lo planteé con un do... while solo para probar y practicar...

Comment: En general no se usan los while o los do while en Web, es muy facil caer en loops infinitos, y generalmente muchas veces al usarlos usamos flags... Pero era una opción, en caso de querer hacerlo con do/while tendrías que crear un contador y podes eliminar el for..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu código no hay nada que vuelva a lanzar el prompt, si es un único prompt podrías directamente hacer el for con un if.

```js
let ingresarNumero = parseInt(
  prompt("Ingresa un numero o si quieres salir ingresa esc")
);

if (ingresarNumero !== "esc" && ingresarNumero !== 0 && ingresarNumero !== 10) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    let resultado = ingresarNumero * i;
    alert(ingresarNumero + " X " + i + " = " + resultado);
  }
} else {
  alert("Terminado");
}
```